# How to associate a Class with more than one behavior with other Class?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, uml, class-diagram

I have some objects that need two types of behavior at the same time when are associated with a Game Class. How is the best way to do this? I'm not seeing any of the GoF Patterns here to help but maybe i'm just with my brain overloaded.

```
interface Actor {}

class Man implements Actor {}

class Woman implements Actor {}

class Game {
    private Map<Actor> actors;
}
```

How to include Player, Referee or LineJudge behavior to this code?

Example:

Game 1, Actor 1 Woman and Referee, Actor 2 Woman and Player

Game 2, Actor 1 Woman and Player, Actor 2 Man and Player

Game 3, Actor 1 Man and Player, Actor 2 Man and Referee, Actor 3 Woman and LineJudge

...

Comment: There's already an interface lurking around in your code. So where is the issue? And while you're tagging this UML why do you come up with code?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the required behavior? Does a male referee behave differently than a female referee, for example? Could you have an attribute 'sex' with values 'Man' and 'Woman' instead of two separate classes Man and Woman? Could you have three separate collections for players, referees and lineJudges in class Game, instead of one collection 'actors'?

Comment: Two types of behaviour at the same time? Do you mean in terms of polymorphism? Or just different operations?

Comment: @ThomasKilian i have the UML diagram but I couldn't upload it cause of site restrictions. An yes, I have a interface but for Man and Woman, which actually have different behavior but are at the same group. I need to add also the other Type.

Comment: @muszeo Yes, two types of behavior (classification) at the same time. Is not the same to be a Woman Player or a Man Player. Different operations.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl yes, Male Referee behave differently than a Female Referee. I could put behavior1 and behavior2 as attributes but I want to make a good design. Yes, I thought about having three collections in Class Game, but I don't know if it is the best, that 's why I'm asking for advices. Thanks!

Comment: Behavior is about doing things in a certain way. All non-super-trivial classes have more than one behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible solutions. I will give the options I think will most likely match your requirements, but there are more possible solutions. What is best in your situation, depends on the exact functionality you need to implement.

### One collection in Game, two attributes in Actor

You may define a class Actor with two attributes, one of type Person, which can be Man or Woman and another of type Participant, which can be Player, Referee or LineJudge.

[image: classdiag1]

### Three collections in Game

Instead of one, you may define three collections of Actors in class Game, one for each role an actor plays in the game. Well, if there's only one Referee, then that is not really a collection.

[image: classdiag2]

Comment: @www-admiraalit-nl is this similar as having a Association Class between Actor and Game?

Comment: @thefloki, No. The association between Actor and Person (a composition with multiplicity=1) is equivalent to an attribute of type Person in class Actor. Similarly, the association between Actor and Participant is equivalent to an attribute of type Participant in class Actor.

Comment: You should remove the aggregates since they are about lifetime of objects. And that's just irrelevant in this context.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, thanks, Game shouldn't aggregate the actors, that's right. However, in the first diagram, Actor is a composition of two objects, a Person and a Participant. In my proposal, an instance of Actor encapsulates the data and behavior of one Person and one Participant. Whenever an Actor receives a method call, it delegates the behavior to one of its components, where relevant. It is an alternative to having Actor-subclasses called ManPlayer, WomanPlayer, ManReferee, WomanReferee etc.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Alas it's just a base for discussions on a white board ;-) Anyhow, I voted to close the question since the OP uses the term behavior without having an idea what it actually means.

Comment: thanks both of you! I will take into account your advices.